# What resources exist for learning Fuzhounese?

Tags: resource-request, chinese

For a long time now, I've been attempting to learn [Fuzhounese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzhou_dialect), a specific dialect of Chinese spoken in Fuzhou City, Fujian Province, China. However, I've found very few resources. All I have found is the examples on the Wikipedia page, some web pages for Mandarin -> Fuzhounese learning, the Omniglot page, and a paper from the City University of Hong Kong concerning a phonetic study of Fuzhounese.

Is anyone aware of any further resources for learning the language?

Comment: What should be the "source language" for these resources? English, Standard Chinese, any other languages?

Comment: Find and contact universities in Fujian. Also, search using the right domain name.

Answer (score 6):

You definitely won't find Fuzhounese on any major online language learning platform, but I did find a pretty decent YouTube playlist [Fuzhounese Lessons (English) 福州话教程 (英文版)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQgKCnewf1Rki9xCAOa3wLiRHctkCHX-a) by AL Language Cafe that explains the basics of the language, which is taught by a native speaker meant for English speakers. The playlist consists of 16 videos, and each one focuses on a different basic topic, like numbers, colors, adjectives, and sentence structure.

Another good resource might be this webpage [language learning resource used by a Chinese university](http://www.study.matsu.edu.tw/language/index.htm#) to teach Fuzhounese.

Answer (score 4):

I found [Fuzhounese.com](http://fuzhounese.com/), a Fuzhounese audio phrase-book. (It describes itself as an "English to Fuzhounese Audio Phrasebook/Dictionary Website".)

Answer (score 0):

1. Fujianese? non audio phrase book, Hippocrene Pub, NY
2. Fuzhou dialect (?), by Wikipedia
3. N Min chapter in classic Hanyu Fangyan Gaiyao, Beijing 1960 89 + ?
4. A few articles in Fangyan Magazine of Chinese Dialect Assoc., ans Zhongguo Yuwen, all 3 in Beijing. issues from 1950 to now